# how to generate alert in android java when connection is lost with remote bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need alert for device paired to android phone in case when it gets out of range from phone Bluetooth. I worked on it and got something about rss can any one help me out.
do i need to send any character to check connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the connection then you are probably blocking on the read() of the InputStream which will throw an IOException when the connection drops.  Catch that and handle correctly.